# How to hide captions below figures using figcaps?

Tags: tables, floats

I'm using figcaps to move the figures at the end of the document and to  generate a list of figures.
The figcaps package displays the figure captions two times: once in the figure list and once below each figure. 
Is there a way to display the captions in the list only?

Here is the code I'm using in the preamble:

```
\usepackage[blank]{figcaps}
\printfigures

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}{\vspace{20pt}}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother
\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@tablepage}{\bigskip}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother
```

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us to help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: Do you want to suppress the entire caption, i.e., including the "Figure <n>:" and "Table <m>:" parts?

Comment: No, I need to leave "Figure<n>" part.

Answer (score 1):

Tables and figures are treated differently by `figcaps`, because the list of captions is displayed separately only for figures.

Just add another patch to those you're already adding.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[blank]{figcaps}
\printfigures

\makeatletter
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}{\def\label}{\renewcommand\caption[2][]{}\def\label}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}{\vspace{20pt}}{\clearpage}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@tablepage}{\bigskip}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text

\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{A square}
\end{figure}

some other text

\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{Another square}
\end{figure}

text

\begin{table}
A table?
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

text

\begin{table}
A table?
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

This will kill the figure captions when the `.lof` file is read back in for printing the figures.

If you want to only kill the caption text, keeping “Figure n”, then you can do

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage[blank]{figcaps}
\printfigures

\makeatletter
\let\@figurepage@makecaption\@makecaption
\patchcmd{\@figurepage@makecaption}{: #2}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@figurepage@makecaption}{: #2}{}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}
  {\def\label}
  {\let\@makecaption\@figurepage@makecaption\def\label}
  {}{}
\patchcmd{\@figurepage}{\vspace{20pt}}{\clearpage}{}{}
\patchcmd{\@tablepage}{\bigskip}{\clearpage}{}{}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

text

\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{A square}
\end{figure}

some other text

\begin{figure}
\rule{3cm}{3cm}
\caption{Another square}
\end{figure}

text

\begin{table}
A table?
\caption{A table}
\end{table}

text

\begin{table}
A table?
\caption{Another table}
\end{table}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Of course, knowledge of the class and package you're using is important, as the patches will not succeed if, for example, you load the `caption` package or a class different from `article`.

Comment: It removes the caption. However the also removes the figure number ("Figure <n>"). Is there a way to remove caption only?

Comment: @AndreaM I added a way, but without a minimal example in the question, it's guessing.

Comment: You're right, sorry. I'm using the svjour3 class for springer journal. I'm trying to set up a minimal example that I'll post online as soon as possible.